# Inserting values into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have created a web form with the following values

- first name
- last name
- address line 1
- address line 2
- city
- state
- contact1
- contact2
- email id
- password
- confirm password...

Upon clicking the submit button, a stored procedure `savedata` is invoked.

The fields `name`, `address` and `contacts` are saved into table `personal_details`, while `email` and `password` are stored into `login_detail`.

The table `personal_details` has columns `user_id int identity(1,1) pk`...
Same `user_id int identity(1,1) fk` is defined in `login_detail` table...

Now, is it possible that 2 users 1 and 2 submit the form at the same time and user1's personal details get pushed in table and then user2's personal details get pushed.

Generating id as 1 and 2 respectively...

but for login details user2 data get pushed first then user1...generating ids 1 and 2... which are wrong....

Is there any other method to get the same ids for both the tables?

thanks

And this is my first question...sorry if I am not able to  frame it properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform the following sequence of steps in a single transaction to ensure the atomicity of this save operation:

1. BEGIN TRANSACTION
2. Insert record into the `personal_details` table.
3. Obtain the user_id corresponding to this new record added.
4. Insert record into the `login_details` table with the user_id as the one obtained in the previous step.
5. COMMIT TRANSACTION.

Also, it doesn't seem appropriate to "vertically partition" the details of a user across two tables when there is a one-to-one correspondence between records in these two tables. You could just have a single table unless there are attributes of a user that carry multiple values for a single user id i.e. one-to-many relationship.

Comment: i am very new to web development..
can you please give me tips on when to break down the table..and these many to one one to one relationships...

and i have only used stored procedure...are transaction any different...
thanks

Comment: You would 'break' a record only when there are multi-valued attributes like one user with multiple addresses, where the user information is stored in one table and each address is stored as a separate record in a different table with a foreign key referencing user_id in the address record. Reg transactions, those BEGIN and COMMIT statements are SQL statements that can be used in stored procedures. you may want to go through a DB transaction tutorial to get a better idea about this.